# How can we have two Usb mice in ubuntu, one right-handed and the other left-handed?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, mouse

I have two mice and I want to use them simultaneously.
The tricky detail is that I want one right-handed and the other left-handed.

Answer (score -1):

This is the twomice.pl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# print "Two Mice\n";
# one left-handed and the other right-handed: cool!

# enter strings from command "xinput list"
my $leftDevice  = "Mouse";
my $rightDevice = "MOUSE";

my $leftHandedOptions  = "1 2 3";
my $rightHandedOptions = "3 2 1";

my $infole = `/usr/bin/xinput list | grep $leftDevice`;
my $infori = `/usr/bin/xinput list | grep $rightDevice`;

my $beginPart = "id=";
my $endPart = "\t";
$infole =~ /$beginPart(.*?)$endPart/; $infole = $1;
$infori =~ /$beginPart(.*?)$endPart/; $infori = $1;

my $commandWords = "/usr/bin/xinput set-button-map";
my $leftMouseCfg = $commandWords . " " . $infole . " " . $leftHandedOptions; 
my $rightMouseCfg = $commandWords . " " . $infori . " " . 
$rightHandedOptions;

#print $leftMouseCfg . "\n";
#print $rightMouseCfg ."\n";

system($leftMouseCfg);
system($rightMouseCfg);
```

Comment: This is useful to prevent Repetitive Strain Injury. When one feels pain in the right hand, they use the left hand, and vice-versa.